# Is it possible to copy a drive backup image, stored by Clonezilla on USB stick A, to a second USB stick B, to be ready in case the USB stick A failed?

Tags: backup, copy, clonezilla

In case a backup image of the main internal SSD drive, loaded with Ubuntu operating system, got made and stored by means of Clonezilla on USB stick A,

would it be possible to copy this image from USB stick A to a second USB stick called B, in case the USB stick called A failed in the future? Doing so I could avoid having to run Clonezilla twice to create the same backup on different USB sticks. But I would like to know whether this is supposed to work.

Thanks

Comment: I asked the question because the image of the whole SSD drive made by Clonezilla is not made up of a single file but of a folder with several files inside. I do not even know how I can tell Clonezilla to make the image as a single file instead of a folder with several files.

Comment: In a word - yes.

Comment: I guess, you can confirm it because you tested that at least once, right?

Comment: Yes, I've done that before. All you'd be doing is copying files to a different location; Clonezilla doesn't care where the image is stored, only the destination of the restoration.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!